# Does Gambit have a forgotten power of creating illusions?

Tags: marvel, x-men, powers

A long long time ago I read a comic book, in which Gambit was training against Wolverine in the Danger Room and Jubilee was in the control chamber.

After a little fight Gambit's eyes starts blinking, Lady Deathstrike appears, then Jubilee yells that she didn't create that image. Lady Deathstrike distracts Wolverine, then Gambit hits Wolverine and says “Bang, you’re dead.”

Was Gambit also an illusionist? Was he playing a mind trick?

Sorry, I don't remember the comic book number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No he's not an illusionist. The issue is Uncanny X-Men #273, and a breakdown of what actually happened was Wolverine and Gambit were dueling in the Danger Room.  Gambit used a robotic doppelganger of Lady Deathstrike to distract Wolverine while he was injured by Reavers to beat him.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambit_(comics)

> After wandering around the world, he encountered a de-aged and
>   powerless Storm, and helped her escape from the Shadow King. He
>   then rescued her from Nanny and the Orphan-Maker, helping her battle
>   them. Afterwards, the young amnesiac Storm, who had reverted to
>   thieving to stay alive, joined Gambit, and she eventually brought him
>   back to the X-Men. Soon after, Gambit helped the X-Men, X-Factor, and
>   New Mutants battle the Genoshans. Only Wolverine expressed his
>   doubts about the Cajun, which led to a Danger Room duel between the
>   two. Gambit was able to triumph by using a robotic doppelganger of
>   Lady Deathstrike to distract Wolverine, while taking advantage of
>   Wolverine's injuries, inflicted by the Reavers.